Question about Whitehead Tower
I'm studying Miller lectures on Algebraic Topology, and I'm stuck in Theorem 68.9 ($\bmod \mathcal{C}$ Hurewicz Theorem ):

Theorem 68.9 (Mod $\mathcal{C}$ Hurewicz theorem). Assume that $\mathcal{C}$ is an acyclic Serre ring. Let $X$ be a simply connected space and let $n \geq 2$. Then $\pi_q(X) \in \mathcal{C}$ for all $q<n$ if and only if $\bar{H}_q(X) \in \mathcal{C}$ for all $q<n$, and in that case the Hurewicz map $\pi_n(X) \rightarrow H_n(X)$ is a mod $\mathcal{C}$ isomorphism.

I'm stuck in the end of their proof, in the final case $\pi_2(X)\neq0$:

But if $\pi_2(X) \neq 0, \Omega X$ is not simply connected. To deal with that, let's take the 2 -connected cover in the Whitehead tower: This is a fibration $Y \downarrow X$ with fiber $K=K\left(\pi_2(X), 1\right)$. This is where the acyclic condition comes in: since $\pi_2(X) \in \mathcal{C}, H_i(K) \in \mathcal{C}$ for $i>0$. The long exact sequence for the pair $(Y, K)$ shows that
$$
\bar{H}_i(Y) \rightarrow H_i(Y, K)
$$
is a mod $\mathcal{C}$ isomorphism. We will apply Proposition 68.8 to $(Y, K) \downarrow(X, *)$, using the fact that $X$ is simply connected and $H_i(X) \in \mathcal{C}$ for $0<i<n$. We find that
$$
H_i(Y, K) \rightarrow H_i(X, *)
$$
is a $\bmod \mathcal{C}$ isomorphism for $i \leq n$. Therefore the projection map $\bar{H}_i(Y) \rightarrow \bar{H}_i(X)$ is a $\bmod \mathcal{C}$ isomorphism for $i \leq n$.
The map $\pi_i(Y) \rightarrow \pi_i(X)$ is an isomorphism for $i \geq 2$, so our hypothesis applies to $Y$, and we can perform the inductive step on it instead of on $X$.

I highlighted the parts that i don't understand. Why does exist a space Y and a fibration $Y\to X$ such that the fiber is $K=K\left(\pi_2(X), 1\right)$, the space Y is 2-connected and the map $\pi_i(Y) \rightarrow \pi_i(X)$ is an isomorphism for $i \geq 2$?
I suppose, as they suggest, that this is related to the Whitehead Tower, but I don't understand how: from what I know, the Whitehead Tower is this diagram

where the spaces $\tau_{\geq n}(X)$ are such that $\pi_k(\tau_{\geq n}(X))$ is $0$ if $k<n$ and is $\pi_k(X)$ if $k\geq n$. But how can I construct the space Y from this diagram?

There is no need to construct anything: The space you're looking for is $\tau_{\geq 2} X$. All the properties you highlight are basic properties of the Whitehead tower that you should be able to find in any textbook that covers the topic (Hatcher, for instance). The only thing in question perhaps is the fibre; for this, write down the long exact sequence in homotopy groups of the fibration and compute its homotopy groups.

I also suggest changing the title: this isn't really about the mod $\mathcal{C}$ Hurewicz theorem but about the Whitehead tower.

Sorry, I got slightly confused by the indices. The space is mean is of course $\tau_{\geq 3} X$ :)

@BenSteffan Thank you, you are right, $\tau_{\geq 3}(X)$ is the space I'm looking for. I've also fixed the title.

Just to get this question answered:
The space you're looking for is $\tau_{\geq 3} X$. Almost all of the properties you highlight are basic properties of the Whitehead tower, except for the structure of the fibre; this follows directly from the associated long exact sequence of homotopy groups.
